# Rewrite recipient of all (except one recipient) outgoing e-mail

Tags: postfix

I have a server that hosts a Java application that is allowed to send out emails.
During testing, I want Postfix to send all outgoing email to test-javaapp@my-company.com, however email that sent to sysadmin@my-company.com needs to be left alone.

Basically:

- `sysadmin@my-company.com --> sysadmin@my-company.com`
- `*@*   --> test-javaapp@my-company.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to share some configuration which works in my use case (deliver *all* messages to my local mailbox regardless of recipient entered).

*Running Ubuntu 14.04, postfix version 2.11.0*

- Add the following lines to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

  ```
  sender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical  
  recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical  
  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
  ```
- Create `/etc/postfix/transport` with content

  ```
  * : yoshi
  ```
- Create `/etc/postfix/sender_canonical`

  ```
  /.+/ yoshi@localhost.com
  ```
- Create `etc/postfix/recipient_canonical/`

  ```
  /.+/ yoshi@localhost.com
  ```
- Update configuration:

  ```
  sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport
  sudo postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_canonical
  sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sender_canonical
  ```
- Restart postfix:

  ```
  sudo service postfix restart
  ```

Now if I run for example the following script:

```
<?php
    mail("iamroot@serverfault.com", "PseudoFaullt to local Inbox", "This is a manual scam mail, please steal money from yourself.\nThank you for the cooperation");
```

I receive it with a rewritten recipient in my local inbox. Actually I'm not sure if you need the sender and transport configuration but I had the impression it wasn't working without. So you might want to give it a shot to shorten the process.

Watch out the `*_maps*` directives in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` are prefixed with `regexp:` rather than `hash:`.

So for your single exception maybe a witty regular expression will do the job.

Very detailed answer about setting up postfix, local inboxes and how to access them with Thunderbird:
https://askubuntu.com/a/209877

Information about `sender_canonincal_maps`:
http://binblog.info/2012/09/27/postfix-rewrite-the-sender-address-of-all-outgoing-mail/

Answer (score 1):

You can use *canonical maps* as specified in Postfix documentation [here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#canonical_maps) and [here](http://www.postfix.org/canonical.5.html).

Comment: Can you share a simple working config? It could be too many thing to handle on postfix server for a application developer cannot focus on this job.

Answer (score 1):

in main.cf

```
recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/canonical_maps_recipient
```

then create /etc/postfix/canonical_maps_recipient and compile with postmap

```
/sysadmin@my-company.com/  sysadmin@my-company.com
/.*/ test-javaapp@my-company.com
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use generic maps as described in the Postfix documentation [here](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic). If you need other address rewriting rules this document also provides the necessary steps.

Comment: Can you give an example on what to write in `/etc/postfix/generic` to acieve my goal? Specificly I would like to know how to handle wildcards.

Comment: I see nothing in the documentation about wildcards, that's why I asked. And if you don't want to help, that's fine but I see **NO** reason for you to be rude. I hope you had fun on my behalf and I also hope this isn't how people asking questions are generally treated here on serverfault.

Comment: @Nifle What about the third line? `@localdomain.local   hisaccount+local@hisisp.example`

Comment: I must be stupid. I can't see how `@localdomain.local` would match for example `foo.bar@foobar.com` and `dick.tracy@comicbook.old`.

Comment: That's right. It matches `*@localdomain.local`. If you want to match `*@*.*` then this is not possible. Postfix is a RFC compliant server.

Comment: Well `*@*.*` is what I asked for, thanks for trying.